# OrientDB Include property from edge connected to specific vertex

Tags: orientdb, orient-sql

I have the following case:

```
       (p:p1)
  V1 ---E1---\ 
              \
               V2 (with properties)
              /
  V1 ---E1---/
       (p:p2)
```

So two vertices of class V1 are connected to another Vertex of type V2, both edges are of the same class E1 which has the property "p".

I would like a query that:

- Targets a V1 instance (by rid)
- Reads all V2 records (including all properties) that are connected to the selected V1 by the edge class E1
- Also includes the property p from the connecting E1-edge in the returned documents.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT *,in('E1')[p] as p FROM (SELECT EXPAND(out('E1')) FROM <V1-rid>) UNWIND p
```

But that would of course give 2 results since the projection returns values from both the E1 edges. I only want to inlcude p form the edge between my selected V1 and V2.

I have some other connections to V2 as well which need to be included, but I wanted to specify the problem more precise to reduce the question complexity and I think (hope) they won't interfere with the answer.

**Update**

Clarification:

I would like the result to be whole V2-records with appended properties "p", so if V2 has properties v2p1:, v2p2, the resulting records should look something like:

```
{
   "v2p1": <value>,
   "v2p2": <value>,
   "p": <value>
}
```

Where the last "p" value is from the edge and the other properties are from the actual V2 records.

Comment: I think you could use http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Match.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select *,traversedEdge(-1).p as p from(traverse outE('E1'),inV('E1') from #21:0) where @class='V2'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this query

```
SELECT FROM (
MATCH {CLASS:v1, AS:v1, WHERE: (@rid=#29:0)}.outE('e1'){AS:e1}.inV('e1'){AS:v2} RETURN v1, e1.p, v2 
)
```

I hope that is clear enough.

Comment: In addition, you can use `SELECT e1_p,v2.* from (` to get directly all the properties

Comment: Thank you for answering, the match syntax is new for me, very useful. However, I would like the query to return the expanded V2 record (all the properties), but with appended propery "p" from E1. I have updated my question to be more clear on the result.

Comment: @IvanMainetti using v2.* breaks the property names (they will be prefixed by "v2_"), I need them to be what they really are, any way around that? I need the actual V2 record, only with one extra property p (from the connected edge).

Comment: you could use the `as`: `SELECT v2.@rid as rid,v2.prop as prop,e1.p as p`    (note that you'll need to return `e1` instead of `e1.p` in the MATCH)

Comment: @IvanMainetti I need all arbitrary properties from V2 though, that's the main problem for me. To get all properties from V2 but also one property from the edge (E1).